# how to create overlapping communities in igraph?

Tags: r, igraph

what I am wondering about is it possible to create overlapping communities in igraph ?

df1 :vertex list and its membership

**EDIT**:id refer to the vertex name and membership is refer to the vertex community id, so vertex `1` is 
belong to two communities : `3` and `2`

```
df1<- structure(list(id = c(1L,2L,3L, 4L, 5L,6L, 7L, 8L,9L), membership = list(c(3, 2),c(2),c(1),c(4),
                                                                             c(4, 1),c(2, 4),
                                                                             c(1),c(1, 3),c(2,1,3))),
                                                           .Names = c("id","membership"),class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
#id membership
#1  1       3, 2
#2  2          2
#3  3          1
#4  4          4
#5  5       4, 1
#6  6       2, 4
#7  7          1
#8  8       1, 3
#9  9    2, 1, 3
```

df2 : edgelist with edge membership

```
df2<- structure(list(id1 = c(1L,2L,5L,8L,9L,4L,6L),id2 = c(3L,5L,8L,1L,2L,3L,7L), membership = list(c(1),c(2),c(1,4),c(3,2),
                                                                           c(1,3, 4),c(3),c(1,2))),
            .Names = c("id1","id2","membership"),class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
    #id1 id2 membership
#1   1   3          1
#2   2   5          2
#3   5   8       1, 4
#4   8   1       3, 2
#5   9   2    1, 3, 4
#6   4   3          3
#7   6   7       1, 2
```

please consider that we want to create a community object :

```
  # diffrent membership vector from df1 
mem <-sapply(1:max(sapply(df1$membership, function(x)length(x))),function(y){
  unlist(lapply(df1$membership,function(x) x[y]))})

         # [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    3    2   NA
# [2,]    2   NA   NA
# [3,]    1   NA   NA
# [4,]    4   NA   NA
# [5,]    4    1   NA
# [6,]    2    4   NA
# [7,]    1   NA   NA
# [8,]    1    3   NA
# [9,]    2    1    3

#create community objects for each membership vector
com<-sapply(1:ncol(mem),function(x) create.communities(membership=mem[,x], algorithm = NULL, merges = NULL,
                        modularity = NULL))

# com
#[[1]]
#Graph community structure calculated with the unknown algorithm
#Number of communities: 4 
#Membership vector:
#[1]  3  2  1  4  4  2  1  1  2

# [[2]]
#Graph community structure calculated with the unknown algorithm
#Number of communities: NA 
#Membership vector:
#[1]  2 NA NA NA  1  4 NA  3  1

#[[3]]
#Graph community structure calculated with the unknown algorithm
#Number of communities: NA 
#Membership vector:
#[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  3

   **Edit**:graph=graph.data.frame(df2,directed=FALSE)
    sapply (1:length(com),function(x) plot.communities(com[[x]],graph))
```

that last line give me an error `Error in membership(x) : Cannot calculate community membership` as it can not compute Number of communities with NA included in the community membership

So,what would be the solution to create these overlapping communities in igraph ?
Thank you in advance and sorry for my long question.

Comment: This is not supported in igraph AFAIK. `create.communities` does not work for overlapping communities.

Comment: thanks for the comment @GaborCsardi , is there any other way to have overlapping communities ?

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do here, but you can define your own class for your communities. E.g. just put a different groups in a list.

Comment: @GaborCsardi,I am not getting your comment unless you are referring to the vertex which are not belong to any communities  .I would be grateful if you clarify this for me.what I want to do is to have overlapping communities, I have vertex list along with the community class Ids which they belong to.

Comment: Yes, that's what I am saying. You already have your communities in `df1`.

Comment: Thanks,so, is there any other way to have overlapping communities in igraph ?

Comment: What does "in igraph" mean?

Comment: @GaborCsardi ,I meant using igraph functions, is there any trick to do that?

Answer (score 1):

1. I am unclear what the column names are referring to in `df1`.
2. It doesn't seem like you use `df2` at all. Why are you defining it?
3. I get an error when it reaches the function `plot.communities`. Is this a personal function?
4. I don't see the variable `graph` anywhere in the code, so that would produce an error as well.

In any case, when you create `mem`, it is first using the first value of `df1$membership`, and then the second, etc. For some (columns 2-4, 7), there is only one element in `membership`, so it returns `NA`. You may have to explicitly check for the length of the element.

So something similar to this might be what you want (but replace the `ifelse` condition if you have to):

> mem <- sapply(1:max(sapply(df1$membership, length)), function(y)
>
> > sapply(df1$membership, function(x)
> >
> > > ifelse(length(x) < y, x[1], x[y])))
>
> > mem
>
> ```
>  [,1] [,2] [,3]
> ```
>
> [1,]    3    2    3
>
> [2,]    2    2    2
>
> [3,]    1    1    1
>
> [4,]    4    4    4
>
> [5,]    4    1    4
>
> [6,]    2    4    2
>
> [7,]    1    1    1
>
> [8,]    1    3    1
>
> [9,]    2    1    3

I also changed the code slightly (e.g. got rid of `unlist(lapply`).

EDIT:
Additionally, when creating `com`, you probably want `lapply` instead of `sapply`.

Comment: thanks for your answer,please see the edit part on defining `graph`(`df2`:is the edge list) and `df1` colnames. `plot.communities` is not a personal function : please see this[link](http://igraph.org/r/doc/communities.html)

Comment: that would consider a solution somehow, but suppose that from the first there are some vertex which are not belong to the any communities.